# Getting a coredump of a third party application

Tags: aix, coredump

I am running on AIX-6.

I want to get a core dump of a third party executable that is in an infinite loop.

I did a `kill -11 $thepid`, it died but it did not dump.

I reviewed my machine settings to make sure it compared with IBM recommended settings:

```
--> lsattr -l sys0 -a fullcore -E
fullcore true Enable full CORE dump True

--> lscore
compression: off
path specification: on
corefile location: /home/alphalfa/tmp
naming specification: on
```

Here is the guide I am following:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1019236

I figured there was some configuration I was missing so I did a test of running `sleep 60` and killing it with `kill -11 $sleeppid`.    That core dumped into alphafa's tmp folder.

The target application is NOT setuid, however it is owner = root.  I changed the owner to alphafa and still did not dump.

What are some things I can try to get this application to coredump or figure out why it will not coredump?